# Finding floor of reciprocal sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Evaluation of
>
> $$\bigg \lfloor \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3^2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(1000)^2}}\bigg\rfloor$$
>
> Where $\lfloor x\rfloor $ is the floor of $x$

Try: It seems like we can solve it using Telescopic sums and that the sum lies between $2$ Telescopic sums, but could not figure out how to solve it.

Could someone help me to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Note the definition of the Generalized Harmonic numbers: $$H_N^{(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac1{n^s}$$ Your value is $$\lfloor H_{1000}^{(2/3)} \rfloor$$

Comment: I don’t think there is something telescopic here. Comparing this sum with an integral, and bounding the error term might help.

Comment: In particular, you can check the answer of the user hypergeometric at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570782/find-floor-of-sum-sum-k-180-k-1-2?rq=1. Follow his idea in your case. You can also work with Abel (partial) summation to estimate your sum.

Comment: The answer is $27$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(sum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B1000%7D1%2Fn%5E(2%2F3)))

Comment: Nice when all the different answers get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{1000}\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{(k+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k+1)}+\sqrt[3]{k^2}}<\sum_{k=1}^{1000}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}}<1+\sum_{k=2}^{1000}\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{(k-1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k-1)}+\sqrt[3]{k^2}}$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{1000}\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{(k+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k+1)}+\sqrt[3]{k^2}}=\sum_{k=1}^{1000}\frac{3(\sqrt[3]{k+1}-\sqrt[3]{k})}{(k+1)-k}=3(\sqrt[3]{1001}-1)>27$

$\displaystyle 1+\sum_{k=2}^{1000}\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{(k-1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k-1)}+\sqrt[3]{k^2}}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{1000}\frac{3(\sqrt[3]{k}-\sqrt[3]{k-1})}{(k-1)-k}=1+3(\sqrt[3]{1000}-1)=28$

So, $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \sum_{k=1}^{1000}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}}\right\rfloor=27$.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to approximate the sum with an integral, and show that the error is bounded by a number less than 1.

In particular, let $$H_{1000}^{(2/3)} = \sum_{k=1}^{1000} k^{-2/3}, \quad I = \int_{x=1}^{1000} x^{-2/3} \, dx.$$  Then we know $$I \le H_{1000}^{(2/3)} < I+1.$$  But $I = 27$, and we are done.

Answer (score 5):

You can bound this summation by two integrals;
$$\int_1^{1001} x^{-2/3}\mathrm{d}x\lt\sum_{k=1}^{1000}k^{-2/3}\lt1+\int_1^{1000}x^{-2/3}\mathrm{d}x$$
Hence we have
$$27\lt3\sqrt[3]{1001}-3\lt\sum_{k=1}^{1000}k^{-2/3}\lt28$$
So as the value of the sum is strictly between $27$ and $28$, the floor of the sum is $27$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left\lfloor {1 \over \root[3]{1}} +
{1 \over \root[3]{2^{2}}} + {1 \over \root[3]{3^2}} + \cdots +
{1 \over \root[3]{1000^{2}}}\right\rfloor} =
\left\lfloor{\sum_{k = 1}^{1000}{1 \over
k^{\color{red}{2/3}}}}\right\rfloor
\\[5mm] = &\
\left\lfloor{\zeta\pars{\color{red}{2 \over 3}} - {1000^{1 - \color{red}{2/3}} \over \color{red}{2/3} - 1} +
\color{red}{2 \over 3}\int_{1000}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{\color{red}{2/3} + 1} }\,\dd x}\right\rfloor.\quad
\pars{~\zeta:\ Riemman\ Zeta\ Function~}
\end{align}
where I used a
[Zeta Function Identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8).

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left\lfloor {1 \over \root[3]{1}} +
{1 \over \root[3]{2^{2}}} + {1 \over \root[3]{3^2}} + \cdots +
{1 \over \root[3]{1000^{2}}}\right\rfloor}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left\lfloor{\zeta\pars{2 \over 3} + 30 +
\color{red}{2 \over 3}\int_{1000}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{5/3}}
\,\dd x}\right\rfloor
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{\zeta\pars{2/3} \approx -2.4476}$
>   
>   and
>   $\ds{0 < {2 \over 3}\int_{1000}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{5/3}}\,\dd x <
> {2 \over 3}\int_{1000}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{5/3}} =
> {1 \over 100} = 0.01}$.

$$
\implies
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left\lfloor {1 \over \root[3]{1}} +
{1 \over \root[3]{2^{2}}} + {1 \over \root[3]{3^2}} + \cdots +
{1 \over \root[3]{1000^{2}}}\right\rfloor} = \bbx{27}
$$